# Express: basic authentication for one route

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, express

I'm trying to make a set of tools to access my database.  Most are to do with accessing data by my webapps, but I also need a page of my express powered site with a password for the site owner to provide an online tool for editing the database; all other routes will not require auth.

With express 3, `basic-auth` made adding such a password easy, but its functionality has been reduced with the middleware in Express 4 and with most of the online tutorials out of date.  The new version of [`basic-auth`](https://github.com/visionmedia/node-basic-auth) will process authentication header info, but **how do I trigger the login popup in the browser**?

The code below is little more than boilerplate, so some hints on the world's simplest login would be welcome.

```
express = require('express')
app = express()
auth = require 'basic-auth'


port = Number(process.env.PORT || 9778);
app.listen port, () ->
    console.log "Listening on port: " + port


app.use '/editor', (req, res) ->
    user = auth req
    if (user == "....") ...
    console.log user


app.get '/editor', (req, res) ->
    # if authenticated send 'editor.html' else....
    res.send 401, "Need password"
```

At present I an adding authentication to access a page and then allowing that page to post to the CRUD node.  I think I should really move to a proper REST API and require authentication on CUD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Server_side) spec, the server can request authentication by sending a `WWW-Authenticate` header with a 401 status code. The following worked for me:

```
res.set({
  'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="simple-admin"'
}).send(401);
```

I put the in my own middleware which looks something like this:

```
var auth = require('basic-auth');

module.exports = function(req, res, next){
  var user = auth(req);
  if(validAuth){ // Here you need some logic to validate authentication
    next();
  } else {
    res.set({
      'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="simple-admin"'
    }).send(401);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on @JustinY this is the end result

```
app.use '/editor', (req, res, next) ->
    user = auth req
    if (user.pass == '******')
        console.log user
        next()
    else
        res.set
            'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="simple-admin"'
        res.send 401, "Need password"


app.get '/editor', (req, res) ->
    res.sendfile 'editor/index.html'
```